# I would like to get more out of my if else statements

Tags: java

I've been messing around way too long on this one and would like to get more out of my if else statements. All of the code works up until a student has a low GPA and or a low SAT score but happens to be the valedictorian of a huge class. I know its unheard of but my code isn't working correct to me if it doesn't qualify that student.

My first post. 
Thanks for any suggestions
Bryan

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("\n\tStudent Qualifier");

    System.out.println("Enter students GPA: ");
    double gpa = in.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Enter students SAT score: ");
    double sat = in.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("\nIf student was valedictorin or salutatorian of a school of 1400 or more, Enter y or n");
    String highestHonors = in.next();
    in.close();     

    if (gpa >= 4.0 && sat >= 1100) 
        studentQualified();
    if (gpa >= 3.5 && sat >= 1300) 
        studentQualified(); 
    if (gpa >= 3.0 && sat >= 1500) 
        studentQualified();
    if (highestHonors == "y")
        studentQualified();
    else
        unQualified();
    }

public static void studentQualified() {
    System.out.println("Student is qualified");
}
public static void unQualified() {
    System.out.println("Student is not qualified");
}
```

}

Comment: Dry run your code. TIp: always use curly braces, even if it is a single line after if condition

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [What does your step debugger tell you?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `||` to combine your tests. Don't use `==` for comparing `String`(s) - you can use `String#equalsIgnoreCase(String)`. Also, I would highly recommend you always use `{}` with `if-else`(s). Like,

```
if ((gpa >= 4.0 && sat >= 1100) || (gpa >= 3.5 && sat >= 1300) ||
        (gpa >= 3.0 && sat >= 1500) || highestHonors.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
    studentQualified();
} else {
    unQualified();
}
```

Comment: Great! I thought about using the || like that but didn't try it. I did it the first time with just two of the statements within one set of parenthesis and that didn't cut it. :-)  Thank you so much. I love this stuff and have been wearing myself out on the little issues that end up being simple.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `equals()` to compare strings, not `==`. `==` will check if the strings are literally the same (i.e. occupy the same space in memory), whereas `equals()` merely checks if the characters are the same.

Something like this should work:

```
if ("y".equals(highestHonors))
```

EDIT: Also, please use curly braces even if you don't think you need them. It makes the code look better and prevents errors when someone wants to add another branch.

Comment: Ok cool. I've read that and still have to learn thru running into it head first I guess. Thank You